# Find a control in Detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I want to find a control which is in the details view. I am new to .net.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use FindControl method for that, like...

```
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)yourDetailsViewID.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Comment: you need to take care your DetailsView mode and template