# How to find TextBox ID in DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

In `DetailsView`I am not using `TemplateField` and `AutoGenerateRow=true` `AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"` . Now I want to know, how to find`TextBox` ID in `DetailsView1_ItemInserting` event?

Comment: `DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1);`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `DetailsView.ItemInserting` event, but possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473409/find-a-control-in-detailsview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the FindControl method of the DetailsView

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        var myLabel = DetailsView1.FindControl("LabelID") as Label;
        myLabel.Text = "something here";
    }
```